# How come I can't set a key value pair as a variable, but I can set it as a parameter?

Tags: ruby, hash, test-first

Working on dictionary lesson from Test First Teaching

In my dictionary.rb file I've got

```
def add(hash)
  @new = Hash[hash]
  @entries.merge!(@new)
end
```

My spec file uses add like this: 
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
Which works.

However, when I'm in pry if i set: 
    a = 'monkeys' => '3'
I get 
    SyntaxError: unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input
    a = 'monkeys' => '3'

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot omit the braces `{}` of a hash literal in that environment. Where you can do it is within arguments, arrays, etc.

Comment: So when using it as an argument, does ruby automatically convert it to the bracketed format?